# Import unknown CSV file format in QGIS

Tags: qgis, csv, import

I have a CSV data sheet that I would like to import in QGIS as a set of polygons. The CSV file contains a column of geometries with long lines of data (see example below). Can somebody tell me how I can import this into QGIS in order to see the polygons?

> 0106000020E61000000100000001030000000100000007000000465C28D96628E43F86DF2C8898F8494006B64134B928E43F5A21943A98F849401B5F5A8CF028E43F7E4EAEA299F849407AE3D3EE2D29E43F261E4D329BF849405F597722D828E43F41BF64829BF849408283070E9B28E43F2CF0BEF299F84940465C28D96628E43F86DF2C8898F84940

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can install the QuickWKT plugin in QGIS, choose `POLYGON (WKB)` as format and insert the binary code in the input box.

The result looks like this, most probably in Halstead, Essex:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the data is exported from PostGIS database. If you want to display it in QGIS

1. Create a database and import this data (or copy paste) to a postGIS database. You can use pgAsmin III for this purpose
2. Connect your QGIS with the created database. then you can see the set of polygons by clicking on the layers(tables of database)